# Subtract from counter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I have a running counter which counts from 0 to 20.000.

But what I would like to have is when a user presses a button, the timer goes back by 250.

So for example, the timer is at 350, it should go back to 100.

I tried the following code:

My timer:

```
  var num = 0;
  var max = 20000;

  function resourcesCounter() {
    if (num > max) {
      window.clearTimeout ("tim");
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('wood').innerHTML = num;
      document.getElementById('iron').innerHTML = num;
      document.getElementById('clay').innerHTML = num;
      num ++;
      var tim = window.setTimeout("resourcesCounter()", 100);
    }
  }
resourcesCounter();
```

When button is pressed go back 250:

```
if(buildingLevel == 'Level 1' && building == 'mainBuilding') {
      if(wood >= 250 && iron >= 150 && clay >= 200) {
        document.getElementById('level-1').innerHTML = 'Level 2';
        document.getElementById('wood').innerHTML = wood - 250;
      } else {
        console.log('Not enough resources');
        console.log(wood + ' ' + iron + ' ' + clay);
      }
    }
```

However, this code does not work. It changes the countdown for a split second and then goes back to its original values.

Comment: So in the second section of code you're subtracting 250 from the `wood` variable, but if `resourceCounter` runs anytime after that, it'll set `wood` back to whatever the value of `num` is. But without all the code I can't tell how often `resourceCounter` actually runs or what else is affecting the `wood` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented your functionality in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ramanbedi1989/fnrt76m5/) fiddle. Please see if it works for you:

```
function startTimer(){
  return setInterval(function(){
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter-container");
    var count = parseInt(counter.textContent.trim());
    count += 1;
    counter.textContent = count;
  }, 100);
};

var timer = startTimer();

var resetButton = document.getElementById('reset-by-250');;
resetButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  clearInterval(timer);
  var counter = document.getElementById("counter-container");
  var count = parseInt(counter.textContent.trim());
  count -= 250;
  if(count < 0){
    count = 0;
  }
  counter.textContent = count;
  timer = startTimer();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 0;
  var max = 20000;

  function resourcesCounter() {
    if (num > max) {
      window.clearTimeout ("tim");
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById('wood').innerHTML = num;
      document.getElementById('iron').innerHTML = num;
      document.getElementById('clay').innerHTML = num;
      num ++;
      var tim = window.setTimeout("resourcesCounter()", 100);
    }
  }
function clickbtn(){
num=num-250;
}
<button onclick="clickbtn()">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never setting `num` when the button is pressed. It will be used when `resourcesCounter` is called again.

```
if(buildingLevel == 'Level 1' && building == 'mainBuilding') {
  if(wood >= 250 && iron >= 150 && clay >= 200) {
    document.getElementById('level-1').innerHTML = 'Level 2';
    // Change num so resourcesCounter() will have the updated value
    num -= 250;
    document.getElementById('wood').innerHTML = num;
  } else {
    console.log('Not enough resources');
    console.log(wood + ' ' + iron + ' ' + clay);
  }
}
```